# How to use C# variables declared in View page inside a jsRender template

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, jsrender

I need to use a variable that is declared in the cshtml view page, inside the js render template. Is it possible?? Below is my code.

```
@{
bool isAdmin = false;
}

<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="ProjectStatus">
{{if Status == 1 && isAdmin}}
<span class="status status-open">{{:Status}}</span>
{{/if}}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Dinesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a C# variable in Javascript, just add @ :

```
{{if Status == 1 && '@isAdmin' == 'True'}}
     <span class="status status-open">{{:Status}}</span>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. i tried using @isAdmin, but missed "== True". Well '@isAdmin' ==  'True' works fine.  :) :)